# Not able to download files from a particular directory in php

Tags: php, ubuntu-16.04, lighttpd

I'm new to php. I want to download files in a directory ('/downloads') which is inside my root server directory. If I place the files in the root directory then then I'm able to download those files but if I place them in '/downloads' directory, I'm not able to download. Here is the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="favicon-32x32.png">
<title>Log Files</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="sorttable.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
<h1>Log Files</h1>

<table class="sortable">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Filename</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Size</th>
        <th>Date Modified</th>

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody><?php

// Adds pretty filesizes
function pretty_filesize($file) {
    $size=filesize($file);
    if($size<1024){$size=$size." Bytes";}
    elseif(($size<1048576)&&($size>1023)){$size=round($size/1024, 1)." KB";}
    elseif(($size<1073741824)&&($size>1048575)){$size=round($size/1048576, 1)." MB";}
    else{$size=round($size/1073741824, 1)." GB";}
    return $size;
}

// Checks to see if veiwing hidden files is enabled
if($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']=="hidden")
{$hide="";
 $ahref="./";
 $atext="Hide";}
else
{$hide=".";
 $ahref="./?hidden";
 $atext="Show";}

$directory = "downloads/";  // or example: $directory = "uploads/";
// opens this directory
$myDirectory = opendir($directory);


// Gets each entry
while($entryName=readdir($myDirectory)) {
   $dirArray[]=$entryName;
}

// Closes directory
closedir($myDirectory);

// Counts elements in array
$indexCount=count($dirArray);

// Sorts files
sort($dirArray);

// Loops through the array of files
for($index=0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) {

// Decides if hidden files should be displayed, based on query above.
    if(substr("$dirArray[$index]", 0, 1)!=$hide) {

// Resets Variables
    $favicon="";
    $class="file";


// Gets File Names
    $name=$dirArray[$index];
    $namehref=$dirArray[$index];

// Gets Date Modified
    $modtime=date("M j Y g:i A", filemtime($dirArray[$index]));
    $timekey=date("YmdHis", filemtime($dirArray[$index]));

// Separates directories, and performs operations on those directories
    if(is_dir($dirArray[$index]))
    {
            $extn="&lt;Directory&gt;";
            $size="&lt;Directory&gt;";
            $sizekey="0";
            $class="dir";

        // Gets favicon.ico, and displays it, only if it exists.
            if(file_exists("$namehref/favicon-32x32.png"))
                {
                    $favicon=" style='background-image:url($namehref/favicon-32x32.png);'";
                    $extn="&lt;Website&gt;";
                }

        // Cleans up . and .. directories
            if($name=="."){$name=". (Current Directory)"; $extn="&lt;System Dir&gt;"; $favicon=" style='background-image:url($namehref/.favicon-32x32.png);'";}
            if($name==".."){$name=".. (Parent Directory)"; $extn="&lt;System Dir&gt;";}
    }

// File-only operations
    else{
        // Gets file extension
        $extn=pathinfo($dirArray[$index], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        // Prettifies file type
        switch ($extn){
            case "png": $extn="PNG Image"; break;
            case "jpg": $extn="JPEG Image"; break;
            case "jpeg": $extn="JPEG Image"; break;
            case "svg": $extn="SVG Image"; break;
            case "gif": $extn="GIF Image"; break;
            case "ico": $extn="Windows Icon"; break;

            case "txt": $extn="Text File"; break;
            case "log": $extn="Log File"; break;
            case "htm": $extn="HTML File"; break;
            case "html": $extn="HTML File"; break;
            case "xhtml": $extn="HTML File"; break;
            case "shtml": $extn="HTML File"; break;
            case "php": $extn="PHP Script"; break;
            case "js": $extn="Javascript File"; break;
            case "css": $extn="Stylesheet"; break;

            case "pdf": $extn="PDF Document"; break;
            case "xls": $extn="Spreadsheet"; break;
            case "xlsx": $extn="Spreadsheet"; break;
            case "doc": $extn="Microsoft Word Document"; break;
            case "docx": $extn="Microsoft Word Document"; break;

            case "zip": $extn="ZIP Archive"; break;
            case "htaccess": $extn="Apache Config File"; break;
            case "exe": $extn="Windows Executable"; break;

            default: if($extn!=""){$extn=strtoupper($extn)." File";} else{$extn="Unknown";} break;
        }

        // Gets and cleans up file size
            $size=pretty_filesize($directory.$dirArray[$index]);
            $sizekey=filesize($directory.$dirArray[$index]);
    }

// Output

 echo("
    <tr class='$class'>
        <td><a href='./$namehref'$favicon class='name'>$name</a></td>
        <td><a href='./$namehref'>$extn</a></td>
        <td sorttable_customkey='$sizekey'><a href='./$namehref'>$size</a></td>
        <td sorttable_customkey='$timekey'><a href='./$namehref'>$modtime</a></td>
    </tr>");
   }
}
?>

    </tbody>
</table>

<h2><?php echo("<a href='$ahref'>$atext hidden files</a>"); ?></h2>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, I'm using lighttpd server. Any help?

Comment: Please can you trim your code to just the minimum necessary to reproduce your problem?

Comment: Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php/845025#845025) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to see if it yields anything.

Comment: wait - just to clarify this bit: `inside my root server directory` - does this mean `downloads` is stored at `/downloads` or `/path/to/project/downloads`?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs it's stored in `/path/to/project/downloads`

Comment: what's the permissions/ownerships on the `/downloads` folder?

Comment: @RiggsFolly It gives me same error for all the files `Warning: filemtime(): stat failed for 10ten in /home/amogh/server/index.php on line 85`

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs the ownership of `/downloads` is given to the user logged in

Comment: @amogh389 the permissions should be the Apache user - not the system user. This is because the script uses Apache to perform the file-related functions - it should be set to `www-data:www-data` or `apache:apache` (depending on system config)

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs I'm using lighttpd server. Should I still change the ownership to `www-data:www-data` ?

Comment: @amogh389 it'll be that service user ... won't know personally, never used it

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs okay. Anyway thanks for the info :)